# Discrete Fourier Transform for text analysis?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft, text-recognition

I would like to determine the number of text-blocks verifying a roughly similar pattern. I have the intuition that I could do it using some Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)-like methodology.

Example:

> Votre date de livraison estimée est :  Mercredi 7 octobre 2015 - 
>   Vendredi 9 octobre 2015
>
> Votre mode de livraison est :  Livraison Rapide
>
> Vos commandes     Votre commande sera expédiée à :
>
> M. X
>
> 120 Road Nowhere
>
> Floor 1 Company Z
>
> City, Zipcode
>
> Country
>
> Votre date de livraison estimée est :  Mercredi 13 mai 2016 - 
>   Vendredi 1 juin 2016
>
> Votre mode de livraison est :  Livraison Rapide
>
> Vos commandes     Votre commande sera expédiée à :
>
> Mrs ZZ
>
> 10, Street Paradise
>
> Another city, another zipcode
>
> Country2
>
> Votre date de livraison estimée est :  Mercredi 7 octobre 2010 - 
>   Vendredi 9 octobre 2011
>
> Votre mode de livraison est :  Livraison Rapide
>
> Vos commandes     Votre commande sera expédiée à :
>
> M. YX
>
> 333, avenue WeirdName
>
> Door 5 Start-up U
>
> SF, ZIP
>
> US

I want to determine that there are 3 blocks (the 3 info for delivery address Amazon-like).

I cannot rely rely on vocabulary (it is not necessarily this kind of text-content). The structure of the blocks is similar (+noise).

Can someone (in)validate this idea, and help me to develop it?

Comment: You may want to look at compression models, since this is what compression strives to do: identify similar text and store it minimally.

Comment: ORganizing and categorizing addresses is one of those near-impossible tasks, right up there with writing a time-date calculator that handles all calendar irregularities correctly.   I recommend not even trying to create your own home-brew address filter.

Comment: To precise further, I'm not interested in the "address" per se. I'm just wanting to extract / cut / cluster block of texts with similar structure. Here it will be 3 addresses (but I do not want / need to know these block of text are addresses!)